# Windows 10 Shortcut Relative Path to Batch File (for Portable App)

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, file-shortcut

Good Morning!
Trying to make a portable set of batch files to help with testing another program. I have the batch files I want with their respective relative paths, but now I am trying to make a shortcut (.lnk) in Windows 10, using a Relative Path, so that I can distribute my program to others. Issue is that every method I have tried in Windows 10 does not work for executing my batch file. I have the shortcut set to run as an admin and the batch files in the same folder as the shortcut. The reason I want a shortcut is because of the Shortcut Key option, which allows me to test more quickly. I just want to be able to launch a batch file in the same folder as the shortcut. To make things easier, I have removed all spaces and even tried a subfolder, but have not had success with any method mentioned (launching via Explorer.exe or CMD.exe). Any ideas outside of something that is not a TRUE Relative Path? Reason why I say TRUE Relative Path, is some have recommended using an Environment Variable with a full file path, to set a variable and somehow consider calling said variable, a relative path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

cd "%~dp0" sets the Command Prompt, to use the directory of the batch file as its working directory.

Comment: How does this solve the problem?  Do you put this into the batch file? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score -1):

I will use temporary VBScript to create the shortcut:

```
@echo off
(
echo Option Explicit
echo Dim WshShell, CurDir, oShortcut, ShortcutName
echo ShortcutName = "Name of your shortcut"
echo ' Next line is removable
echo MsgBox^("Hi! This is a demo script showing how to create shortcut in current folder."^)
echo Set WshShell = CreateObject^("WSCript.Shell"^)
echo CurDir = "%cd%"
echo oShortcut = WSHShell.CreateShortcut^(CurDir ^& "\" ^& ShortcutName ^& ".lnk"^)
echo With oShortcut
echo  .TargetPath = Curdir ^& "\" ^& "%~nx0"
echo  .WindowStyle = 4
echo  .IconLocation = "cmd.exe"
echo  .Save
echo End With
echo ' Next line is removable
echo MsgBox^("Done!"^)
) >>CrShortcut.vbs
cscript //nologo CrShortcut.vbs
del /f /q CrShortcut.vbs
REM Next line is omittable
pause >nul 2>&1
REM Continue here
exit /b 0
```